# Unlocking "bonus" stuff

Tags: jet-set-radio

In *Jet Set Radio* HD (XBLA), there is a "Bonus" menu under "System" (the pinball machine). There are eight unlockables (including a movie and what appear to be audio tracks):

1. Jet Set Radio Documentary
2. The Concept of Love
3. Fly Like a Butterfly
4. Funky Dealer
5. Shape Da Future
6. Teknopathetic
7. Oldies but Happies
8. Like It Like This Like That

How can I unlock all of this bonus stuff?

Comment: I unlocked the documentary and the song Fly Like a Butterfy. I think it might have to do with completing levels with a 'Jet' rating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the songs, here are the conditions:

> - The Concept of Love - Complete the Tutorial
> - Fly Like a Butterfly - Unlock Gum and Tab (story-related unlocks)
> - Funky Dealer - Complete Chapter 1
> - Shape Da Future - Complete Chapter 2
> - Teknopathic - Complete Chapter 3
> - Oldies but Happies - Unlock all Characters
> - Like it Like This Like That - Complete all missions with any ranking.

[source](http://www.xbox360achievements.org/game/jet-set-radio-hd/guide/%20%27unlock%20conditions%20source%27%27)

Also, how to unlock all the characters:

> - Garam: Challenges you after you beat Monsters Of Kogane
> - Mew: Challenges you after Benten Boogie
> - Yoyo: Challenges you after you beat Poison Jam and Noise Tanks
> - Combo: After you beat Chapter 1
> - Cube: After you beat Chapter 1
> - Piranha: Challenges you after you beat "Explosion" (Shibuya Golden Rhino mission)
> - Slate: Challenges you after you beat "Fight Or Flight" (Kogane Golden Rhino mission)
> - Poison Jam: Get Jet rating on all Kogane story missions
> - Unmasked Poison Jam: Hold X when selecting Poison Jam
> - Noise Tanks: Get Jet rating on all Benten story missions (including Behind The Mask)
> - Love Shockers: Get Jet rating on all Shibuya story missions
> - Goji: Get Jet on Bantam Street and Grind Square
> - Pots: Unlock every other character, then on a second playthrough play "Monster Of Kogane" level before "Benten Boogie". A Noise Tank will challenge you after Chapter 2, and if you win, you unlock Pots.

[source (last post)](http://www.xbox360achievements.org/forum/showthread.php?t=387706)